# Format the datetime value in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

The datetime value saved in database is "`2014-06-30 02:52:51.210201`".

This is also the value displayed by Yii.

What is the best approach to display it as "`30-06-2014 02:52:51`" everywhere?

Found this in [Yii's wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/684/save-and-display-date-time-fields-in-different-formats-in-yii2/) but don't know how to use it:

> You can configure yii\i18n\formatter to control your global date
>   formats for display for your locale. You can set something like this
>   in your config file that you can access across
>
> ```
> 'formatter' => [
>  'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
>  'dateFormat' => 'd-M-Y',
>  'datetimeFormat' => 'd-M-Y H:i:s',
>  'timeFormat' => 'H:i:s', ]`
> ```
>
> Then you can display your date times anywhere using the formatter
>   specified formats:
>
> `echo \Yii::t('app', 'Today is {0, date}', $yourTimeStampAttr);`

**UPDATE**

I create a custom attribute for the model to retrieve the time

```
public function getFormattedCreateTime()
{
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', $this->create_time)->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
}
```

another problem though, how do I use this attribute for search in Yii 2's GridView ? thanks

**SOLVED**

can add the custom attribute for search by inherits the search function

Comment: Whether milliseconds are necessary to you in general?

Comment: @frops: it's the default format in the postgres

Comment: Wiki Link is missing!

Comment: ok found and added it!

Comment: Can you give an exemple of the inherited search ?

Answer (score 21):

```
\Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime("2014-06-30 02:52:51.210201", "php:d-m-Y H:i:s");
```

Second parameter alow you set a custom format as specified in the [ICU manual](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime). 
Or you can set php [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) format with `php:` prefix.

As mentioned in Yii2 documentation the following types of value are supported:

- an integer representing a UNIX timestamp
- a string that can be [parsed to create a DateTime
  object](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php).
- a PHP [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object

If you have custom date string you can use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function:

```
$dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y  H:i:s", '31/01/2015');
\Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($dateTime, "php:d-m-Y  H:i:s");
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this is good solution to the problem.

Comment: @dmvslv This works !
but the value displayed is : '30-52-2014 02::', and the format that I use is 'd-m-Y H:i:s', what's the problem ?

Comment: Its not working with format 31/01/2015 i.e. for / separator.

Answer (score 11):

You have found the right solution yourself, setting the formatter in the config.

Based on what skeleton app you've used (for example official advanced template) then you add this to your config file main.php.

**/your-app/config/main.php**

or

**/common/config/main.php**

Should look like this:

```
<?php
return [
   'components' => [
       ...
       'formatter' => [
           'dateFormat' => 'd-M-Y',
           'datetimeFormat' => 'd-M-Y H:i:s',
           'timeFormat' => 'H:i:s',

           'locale' => 'de-DE', //your language locale
           'defaultTimeZone' => 'Europe/Berlin', // time zone
      ],
   ],
   // set target language
   'language' => 'de-DE',
],
?>
```

See [here in the documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#properties) for the properties you can use in formatter.

Then in your app you can use the formatter without format strings.

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($yourDate);
Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($yourDatetime);
Yii::$app->formatter->asTime($yourTime);
```

or in data widgets (like GridView) use the "format" property

```
'$yourDate:date',
'$yourDatetime:datetime',
'$yourTime:time',
```

Comment: `$yourDatetime:datetime` this shows the date time value with Hour field increased by 1 hour. for example if datetime value from table is **2016-03-15 09:00:02** then this code displays **Mar 15, 2016, 10:00:02 AM**

Answer (score 2):

if you want to show in your view then just write your code like this

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
     [ 
      'label' => 'Modified Date',
      'value' => date("d-M-Y h:i:s",  strtotime($model->client_modified_date)),
     ]
   ],
]) ?>
```

its show the format of **dd-mm-yy h:i:s**

Comment: You could try client_modified_date:date for value. This will take the  format from formatter component you configured in your app config. The pattern is attribute:format:label

Comment: you should wrap `value` expression into anonymous function if you going to use $model. otherwise there will be an error.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery plugin datepick and input field. So, without widget resolved problem the next way:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'released_date')->textInput(['maxlenght' => 255, 'value' => date( 'd-M-Y', strtotime( $model->released_date ) )]); ?>
```

where `$model->released_date` is a date in mysql format timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show date and time from time stamp value like `created_at`,`updated_at` then!

GridView:

```
'created_at:datetime', // Jul 28, 2016, 8:29:38 PM
'updated_at:datetime', // Jul 28, 2016, 8:29:38 PM
```

Same as DetailVeiw:

```
'created_at:datetime', // Jul 28, 2016, 8:29:38 PM
'updated_at:datetime', // Jul 28, 2016, 8:29:38 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this inside your GridView widget

```
'$yourDate:date',
'$yourDatetime:datetime',
'$yourTime:time'
```

for example

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            'id',
            '$yourDate:date',
['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```